# console.log / javascript/ index.html not linked

Tags: javascript

I am working on an html document folder (a form), and linked it to the js document folder. But all the changes made to the html from the js document folder are not posted on the console. I click inspect, console, and the are not linked. Can someone help? Thanks

this is the code on Visual studio:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div container="container">
        <h1>Form</h1>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Example textarea</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
      </div>
      
      <script src="script.js"></script> 


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

in the js folder, this command does not show anything on the console.

console.dir(document);

Comment: You must supply a [relative URL](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/css-html-email/#:~:text=A%20Relative%20Reference%20provides%20a,defaults%20to%20the%20current%20directory.) from the .html file to the .js file. So, if the .js file is in a sibling folder called "JS", you'd need `<script src="js/script.js">,/script>`.

Comment: Since I‘m on my phone I can only guess, but there is a closing script tag which shouldn‘t be there,  also if the js file is in the root folder use ./ in front of the path to the js file, else provide the full relative path to the file.

Comment: @TD3V While that is an error, it wouldn't prevent the first `script` from working. Also, to specify the web root, you only need `/` at the beginning of the  path.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `But all the changes made to the html from the js document folder are not posted on the console`. You mean your script is changing the DOM but neither the browser window nor the inspector show any changes? I.e. it's like the script doesn't run? Did you look at the browser's console? It should show the failed attempt at loading the script.

Comment: Also, [`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">`](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon) is invalid HTML.

Comment: @nadia.shim Yes, the first comment above should read: `<script src="js/script.js"></script>`

Comment: To ChrisG, yes that is the issue. I 've also  tried the link real shortcut or js/script.js but still not working.

Comment: What is the name of the folder you have your JavaScript file(s) in AND where is that folder located in relation to where you have the HTML file(s)?

Comment: called script.js and saved in a seperate file from index.html file  both under a main folder in visual studio code

Comment: So both files are in the same folder?

Answer (score -1):

How are you running/accessing this file?

Also I think there's an extra closing script tag, that could be causing the error as well

You could try installing a vs code extension "Live Server" that'll spin up a local server out-of-the-box with zero configuration.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Comment: There is no need for a server in order to have this code work.